# What happens if I upload an .apk to Google Play to all countries with no translations?

Tags: android

If the country doesn't support English, will they remove the app in those countries? Remove the app completely? Just wondering.

Comment: Which country doesn't support English?

Comment: I mean countries where they don't speak English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It won't be removed. If you only write one language into the app, it will only display one language, whatever it is. It will still be available to anyone in that country that can access the Play Store